# Delete dataset attribute from HDF5 file

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I have a hdf5 file I want to modify by deleting an attribute of one of the datasets and save the file without further changes. I can do this in hdfview, but I need something that's scriptable because it needs to be applied to a large number of files.

I tried writing a script in python, using h5py:

```
import h5py
inF = h5py.File("Filename.h5", 'r')
dSet = inF['/data/myDataset']
del dSet.attrs['myAttrName']
```

But I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/attrs.py",
>   line 75, in **delitem**
>       h5a.delete(self._id, self._e(name))   File "h5a.pyx", line 135, in h5py.h5a.delete (h5py/h5a.c:2682) KeyError: "unable to delete
>   attribute (Attribute: Can't delete message)"

`print dSet.attrs['myAttrName']` produces the correct value, proving I can access the attribute.

Is there any other ways to do this? Maybe using h5repack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using one of the hdf tools - h5copy:

```
h5copy -p -i inputFile.h5 -o outputFile.h5 -s /inputDataSetName -d /outputDataSetName -f noattr
```

Since all of the files I have to process have the same datasets and it's fairly small number of dataset,s I wrote a shell script that calls h5copy on each.

Note that running h5copy on the a group will not remove the attributes of all datasets in that group.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the h5py script is that you've opened the file in read-only mode ("r").  You need to open with append, like so:

```
inF = h5py.File("Filename.h5", 'a')
```

Comment: This is the right answer.
As of now (Python: 3.8.5, h5py: 2.10.0), the error message is clearer on that topic `KeyError: 'Unable to delete attribute (no write intent on file)'` when the file is open in read-only mode.